# Cake PHP class variables

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a class in CakePHP with several methods that contain these two lines:

```
App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
```

Which is then called

```
$result = $HttpSocket->post('http://domain.com', $dataArr);
```

How can I put the first two lines in to a class variable `$socket` which will then allow me to do

```
$result = $socket->post("http://domain.com", $dataArr);
```

I'm not sure if it should go in a `__construct` or ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    private $socket;

    public function __construct(){
        App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');
        $this->socket = new HttpSocket();
    }

    public function my_function($data) {
        $result = $this->socket->post("http://domain.com", $data);
    }
}
```

hope this helps